Simple dev server for a small module-based vanilla JavaScript web application
I have a simple single page web application without any frameworks which gets published as-is from the master branch to GitHub pages.
Dependencies are imported as ES6 modules from content delivery networks like this:
import { SVG } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.esm.js";
import { myfunc } from "./mylocalfile.js";

I quite like this approach because I do not need a bundler, node/npm and so and can deploy it to GitHub pages without a build action.
However my browsers (Firefox and Chrome) do not allow loading ES6 modules over the file protocol so I need some kind of dev server. python -m http.server does not set any cache headers so it either gives me outdated HTML/CSS/JavaScript or  I need to disable cache which will reload external dependencies from the CDN which is too slow.
Right now I am using NPM serve which fixes the caching issue and is fast, however I wonder if I am missing out on not using a dedicated dev server like Vite. However Vite also has a build tool/bundler, which I do not need.
Should I still switch to Vite or some other dedicated dev server and just use it without the build tool, and if yes, which one would be the best? Or should I just stick with the current software and workflow?
